# HTML5 video mediacontroller hide behind dialog

Tags: android, html, video

I have a webview to display html5 video, my objective is to display the video in fullscreen. In order to do this, I have to extend the WebChromeClient Class and override the method onShowCustomView and OnHideCustomView. The project I am currently working on is a library project, so the activity_main.xml is not available. Then I use a dialog to display the video in full screen. The problem is the mediacontroller is not showing. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {  
    if (customView != null){
        customViewCallback = callback;
        callback.onCustomViewHidden();
        return;
    }

    root  = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
    customViewCallback = callback;
    customView = view;  

    root.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    root.addView(customView,params);

    Button closeBtn = new Button(mContext);
    closeBtn.setText("Close");
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onHideCustomView();
        }           
    });
    root.addView(closeBtn);




    mDialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    mDialog.setContentView(root);
    mDialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onHideCustomView() {
    if (mDialog != null) {  
        mDialog.dismiss();
        customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
    }

    mDialog = null;
    customView = null;
    root = null;
}
```

customView is a View, root is a RelativeLayout and they are members of the extended WebChromeClient class.  How to show the media controller, anybody helps? By the way, is there any ways to customize the media contorller in this case?

Comment: Did you solve this ? I'm facing the same behaviour